# Why is StoppingTest in red? What other option to stop NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, code-review, version-13.2

The following stripped down code works, but I'm experiencing some strange warnings:  from an old document made with **Mathematica 7.0** (but used in **version 13.2**), I'm getting several warning messages about "*Event location failed to converge to requested accuracy or precision...*".  The output is okay, though.  When I copy paste the exact same code in a new document made with **Mathematica 13.2**, I don't get any warning/error message, but the `StoppingTest` is drawn in red.  So the issue lies there (indicated with the comment (* ISSUE IS HERE! *) in the code below).

```
MomMagn = {1, 1, 1};  (* norm of each magnetic moment *)
thetaMu = {45, 45, 0}Pi/180;  (* inclinaison relative to Z axis *)
phiMu = {90, 270, 0}Pi/180;  (* azimutal angle around Z axis *)

source[k_] := {{3, 0, 0}, {-8, 0, 0}, {0, 8, 0}}[[k]] (* position of each magnetic sphere *)

rotationX[k_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[thetaMu[[k]]], -Sin[thetaMu[[k]]]}, {0, Sin[thetaMu[[k]]], Cos[thetaMu[[k]]]}} (* rotation matrix around X axis *)
rotationZ[k_] := {{Cos[phiMu[[k]]], -Sin[phiMu[[k]]], 0}, {Sin[phiMu[[k]]], Cos[phiMu[[k]]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}  (* rotation matrix around Z axis *)
mu[k_] := MomMagn[[k]]rotationZ[k].rotationX[k].{0, 0, 1} (* magnetic moments *)

Nspheres = Length[MomMagn]; (* number of magnetic spheres *)

(* magnetic field definition: *)
xyz[s_] := {x[s], y[s], z[s]}
r[s_, k_] := Norm[xyz[s] - source[k]]
dipole[s_, k_] := 3 mu[k].(xyz[s] - source[k])(xyz[s] - source[k])/r[s, k]^5 - mu[k]/r[s, k]^3
magneticfield[s_] := Sum[dipole[s, k], {k, 1, Nspheres}]

(* magnetic field lines definition: *)
Nlines = 15;

theta[n_] := Which[n == -2, 20, n == -1, 0, n == 0, 0, n == 1, 20, n == 2, 27.5]Pi/180
phi[n_, m_] := If[n > 0, m 2 Pi/Nlines, 0]
sphericalstart[n_, m_] := If[n < 0, -1, 1] {Sin[theta[n]] Cos[phi[n, m]], Sin[theta[n]] Sin[phi[n, m]], Cos[theta[n]]}
linestart[n_, m_, k_] := rotationZ[k].rotationX[k].sphericalstart[n, m] + source[k]

magneticCurves[n_, m_, k_] := NDSolve[{
    x'[s] == If[n < 0, -1, 1]{1, 0, 0}.magneticfield[s]/Norm[magneticfield[s]],
    y'[s] == If[n < 0, -1, 1]{0, 1, 0}.magneticfield[s]/Norm[magneticfield[s]],
    z'[s] == If[n < 0, -1, 1]{0, 0, 1}.magneticfield[s]/Norm[magneticfield[s]],

    x[0] == {1, 0, 0}.linestart[n, m, k],
    y[0] == {0, 1, 0}.linestart[n, m, k],
    z[0] == {0, 0, 1}.linestart[n, m, k]
    }, {x, y, z}, {s, 0, 500},
    Method -> Automatic, MaxSteps -> Automatic,
    StoppingTest -> (Apply[Or, Table[EuclideanDistance[xyz[s], source[kk]] < 1, {kk, 1, Nspheres}]] || r[s, k] > 25)] (* ISSUE IS HERE! *)

Do[magneticCurves[n, m, k], {k, 1, Nspheres}, {n, -2, 2}, {m, 1, Nlines}]

Smin[n_, m_, k_] := (x/.magneticCurves[n, m, k])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]] (* start of each field line *)
Smax[n_, m_, k_] := (x/.magneticCurves[n, m, k])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]] (* end of each field line *)

magneticGraph[n_, m_, k_] := ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[xyz[s]/.magneticCurves[n, m, k]], {s, Smin[n, m, k], Smax[n, m, k]}]

Show[Table[magneticGraph[n, m, k], {n, -2, 2}, {m, 1, Nlines}, {k, 1, Nspheres}], PlotRange -> All]
```

Preview of what the code is doing:

[image]

So what should I use instead of `StoppingTest`?  If I remove completely this part, the output isn't right at all.  The field lines output is right when I still use the red StoppingTest line.  I don't understand what's going on here.

**Note:** This code is slow (on a Silicon Mac M2 Pro with 32GB ram).  This is NOT a concern to me.  The issue isn't about the compilation speed and I don't need to optimize the whole code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StoppingTest` isn't available anymore in the newer versions of Mathematica. You should use [`WhenEvent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) or ["EventLocator" method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html) instead.

For example:

```
magneticCurves[n_, m_, k_] := 
 With[{conds = Or@@Table[EuclideanDistance[xyz[s], source[kk]] < 1,
   {kk, 1, Nspheres}] || r[s, k] > 25}, 
  NDSolve[{x'[s] == 
     If[n < 0, -1, 1] {1, 0, 0} . magneticfield[s]/Norm[magneticfield[s]], 
    y'[s] == 
     If[n < 0, -1, 1] {0, 1, 0} . magneticfield[s]/Norm[magneticfield[s]], 
    z'[s] == 
     If[n < 0, -1, 1] {0, 0, 1} . magneticfield[s]/Norm[magneticfield[s]], 
    x[0] == {1, 0, 0} . linestart[n, m, k],
    y[0] == {0, 1, 0} . linestart[n, m, k], 
    z[0] == {0, 0, 1} . linestart[n, m, k],
    WhenEvent[conds, "StopIntegration"]
  }, 
  {x[s], y[s], z[s]}, 
  {s, 0, 500}, 
  Method -> Automatic, MaxSteps -> Automatic]]
```

Comment: Why is the cond event declared inside a With environment, and not the other conditions?

Comment: @Cham `With` applies to the whole block

Comment: @Cham, because `r[s, k]` has to be evaluated to `Sqrt[...] > 25` before it is fed into `NDSolve`.

Comment: @Domen, then what about the r[s, k] < 1 condition?  Why not put it alongside with >25?  I don't understand this part

Comment: @Cham, I have simplified the code to make it more clear. Let me know if there is still anything unclear.

Comment: If I use **{cond = (r[s, k] > 25 || 
    Apply[Or, Table[r[s, kk] < 1, {kk, 1, Nspheres}]])}** inside the *With* environment, I get exactly the same output (which is nice) as using the *StoppingTest* line, and still get the error messages: "Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or \
precision within 100 iterations between ..."

Comment: I want to solve these error messages.  I don't know how.

Comment: Please use ```Clear["Global`*"]``` first to clear all definitions, and rerun the code. It should work fine, as seen [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ykDM.png).

Comment: I do use this command on all of my codes.  Still getting the error messages.  Maybe not related to the conditions, I don't know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147522/discussion-between-domen-and-cham).